# add background color on bootstrap grid column with preventing coloring default grid column padding

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

my problem is I need to color a one bootstrap grid column background instead of coloring full grid-column, add background color on-grid except default padding.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 faq-box">
        <div class="faq-titile">
             <h4>faq title</h4>
         </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 pl-0">   
        .......
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.faq-box{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color:#EBF3FF ;
}
```

[image]
In here I need to prevent color full grid column, only add background color without coloring bootstrap grid default left padding(15px)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a div inside the column, than, add the background to this div.:

```css
.padding-here{
  padding:2em;
  background:#c4c4c4;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.padding-here-too{
  padding:2em;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid black;
  
}
.padding-here-too div{
  background:#c4c4c4;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="padding-here">padding here</div>
<div class="padding-here-too">
  <div>
    padding here too
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `box-sizing: border box` then padding and border will be included in the width.

```css
.faq-box{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color:#EBF3FF ;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 faq-box">
        <div class="faq-titile">
             <h4>faq title</h4>
         </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 pl-0">   
        .......
    </div>
</div>
```

These examples make it clear:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.parent {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 140px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 10px solid #349;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.example1, .example2, .example3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
}

.example1 {
  background: rgba(255,230,40,.8);
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.example2 {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.example3 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.example2, .example3 {
  border: solid rgba(255,230,40,.8) 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="example1">
    content-box<br>
    border: none<br>
    padding: none
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="example2">
    content-box<br>
    border: 10px<br>
    padding: 5px
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="example3">
    border-box<br>
    border: 10px<br>
    padding: 5px
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you @thimothy for your contribution

Answer (score 1):

In your case your row needs padding

```
<div class="row p-5">
```